# How to detect a Dialog on activity while running android junit test case

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm using `AcivityInstrumentTestCase2` and when a dialog is shown, how do I get instance of dialog or how do I know what dialog is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override 
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean nowFocused)
{
    Father.print("Focus changed to " + nowFocused);
    //implementation
}
```